# Flutter how to toggle (flip) camera without re-recording the video?

Tags: flutter, camera

I'm using the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package to shoot videos in my app. I added a toggle button, to change between the front and back cameras.

**In order to toggle between the cameras, I need to initiate a new recording.**

This is my code:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:tenant_app/maintenance_request/bloc/maintenance_request_bloc.dart';

class MaintenanceRequestRecordingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MaintenanceRequestRecordingPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaintenanceRequestRecordingView();
  }
}

class MaintenanceRequestRecordingView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MaintenanceRequestRecordingView({super.key});

  @override
  State<MaintenanceRequestRecordingView> createState() =>
      _MaintenanceRequestRecordingViewState();
}

class _MaintenanceRequestRecordingViewState
    extends State<MaintenanceRequestRecordingView> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  bool _isRecording = false;
  bool _isFlashOn = false;
  bool _isPaused = false;
  late CameraController _cameraController;
  late List<CameraDescription> _availableCameras;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _initCamera({
    CameraLensDirection direction = CameraLensDirection.back,
  }) async {
    _availableCameras = await availableCameras();
    _cameraController = CameraController(
      getCameraBasedOnLensDirection(direction: direction),
      ResolutionPreset.max,
    );
    await _cameraController.initialize();
    await _startRecording();
  }

  CameraDescription getCameraBasedOnLensDirection({
    required CameraLensDirection direction,
  }) =>
      _availableCameras
          .firstWhere((camera) => camera.lensDirection == direction);

  Future<void> _startRecording() async {
    await _cameraController.prepareForVideoRecording();
    await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();
    setState(() {
      _isRecording = true;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _stopRecording(
      MaintenanceRequestBloc maintenanceRequestBloc,) async {
    final file = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
    setState(() => _isRecording = false);
    maintenanceRequestBloc.add(
      MaintenanceRequestEventChangeStatus(RequestScreen.review, file.path),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Recording'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(_isFlashOn ? Icons.flash_on : Icons.flash_off),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _isFlashOn = !_isFlashOn;
              });
              _isFlashOn
                  ? _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.torch)
                  : _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            CameraPreview(_cameraController),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  // centers row's pause and stop buttons
                  const IconButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    icon: SizedBox(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _isPaused = !_isPaused;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    _isPaused
                                        ? Icons.play_arrow
                                        : Icons.pause,
                                  ),
                                  Text(_isPaused ? 'Resume' : 'Pause'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () =>
                                _stopRecording(
                                  context.read<MaintenanceRequestBloc>(),
                                ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: const [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.stop,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                  Text('Stop'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final newCameraDirection =
                        _cameraController.description.lensDirection ==
                            CameraLensDirection.front
                            ? CameraLensDirection.back
                            : CameraLensDirection.front;
                        await _initCamera(direction: newCameraDirection);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.flip_camera_android,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I toggle the camera a new video is recorded. As you can see, I flipped the camera two times, so now I'm having 3 mp4 files recorded.

[image]

I want to toggle between the cameras, without initiating a new recording. I want it to be one shoot.

**Is it possible to toggle between cameras without `_cameraController.startVideoRecording` re-recording the video?**

How do I do that using the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package? Right now my only solution is to merge the mp4 files locally.

Comment: It is because you are calling `_startRecording()` inside `_initCamera()`. You need to remove it from there and only call when you actually press 'start/record' button

Comment: I know that, But I think you must startVideoRecording between toggles. And that's my problem.

Comment: Updated my question if it was not clear